# How to efficiently make multiple -replace commands in powershell

Tags: powershell

I can see myself that it's stupid to use the `get-content` command multiple times, does anyone know how to make this more efficient?

```
(Get-Content hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html) -replace '&quot;', '"' | set- 
content hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html
(Get-Content hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html) -replace 'ae', 'æ' | set-content 
hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html
(Get-Content hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html) -replace 'o/', 'ø' | set-content 
hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html
(Get-Content hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html) -replace 'aa', 'å' | set-content 
hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html
```

I hope I explained this well enough, if there was something you didn't understand then just write, then I'll try to clarify.

BTW does anyone know how to make it case sensetive, like AE=Æ and not æ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action the replaces in one go and you only need to use `Get/Set-Content` once:

```
(Get-Content hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html) -replace '&quot;','"' -replace 'ae','æ' -replace 'o/','ø' -replace 'aa', 'å' | Set-Content hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html
```

Same but using backtick to split command over multiple lines to make it a bit more readable:

```
(Get-Content hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html) `
    -replace '&quot;','"' `
    -replace 'ae','æ' `
    -replace 'o/','ø' `
    -replace 'aa', 'å' |
    Set-Content hvor_har_vi_vaeret_i_aar.html
```

Comment: WHATT?? I swear i tried that yesterday?? I must have misspelled something... :( sorry for the inconvince this may have created....

Comment: Easy to miss something when you've been working on it for a while :)

Comment: Getting stuck on simple syntax issues is a right-of-passage for PowerShell developers. +1 for backticks, they greatly increase clarity!

Comment: Btw do you know how to make it case sensetive, like AE=Æ and not æ?

Comment: `-creplace` is the case sensetive version.

Answer (score 0):

Another method you can use, which personally I prefer because it very easily allows you to pass these as parameters into a function, is to declare a 2D array and loop through it:

```
$string = 'abcdef'

$replaceArray = @(
                 @('a','1'),
                 @('b','2'),
                 @('c','3')
                )

# =============

$replaceArray | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $string = $string -replace $_[0],$_[1]
    }

Write-Output $string
```

> 123def

It's even easier if you only want to remove items from your string, because you can do something like this: `'a','b','c' | % {$string = $string -replace $_}`